# Flutter Icons in Row "right overflowed by X pixels"

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am trying to build a Tab Bar in Flutter animate it closing and opening. While it's opening, because the icons inside a Row are only fully visible once the Row is extended, it gives me the famous Flutter "overflowed" error.

I tried reading about possible solutions, but most are connected to text overflow issues. I've tried wrapping my Row in an "Expanded", but I realized it doesn't make much sense anyway. I had a look at other solutions, but I cannot find anything similar to my issue with Icons in a Row widget.

I hope someone can help me and hopefully this helps someone in the future.

````
  bool selected = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          selected = !selected;
        });
      },
      child: Center(
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          padding: selected ? EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0, horizontal: 12.0) :
          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0, horizontal: 30.0),
          width: selected ? 48 : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.85,
          child: selected ? Row(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.favorite),
            ],
          )
              : Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.home),
              Icon(Icons.message),
              Icon(Icons.add),
              Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
              Icon(Icons.person_outline),
            ],
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.grey, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
          duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}```

[Fig.1][1]

Fig. 1

[Fig.2][2]

Fig. 2


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkjPM.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnDTi.jpg
````

Comment: Overflow is caused when you try to add a widget where there is not sufficient space. Consider passing lower padding value and width. You are setting so much padding which might be the reason as it's taking so much of space from a limited space

Answer (score 0):

There are many options who to deal with it, depending on what you need. I've add two of them

1. First. Wrap every icon in `Flexible Widget` [Flutter Widget of the Week about it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CI7x0mAZiY0)

[image]

```
bool isSelected = false;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      setState(() {
        isSelected = !isSelected;
      });
    },
    child: Center(
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        padding: isSelected
            ? EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0, horizontal: 12.0)
            : EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0, horizontal: 30.0),
        width: isSelected ? 48 : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.85,
        child: isSelected
            ? Icon(Icons.favorite)
            : Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  _icon(Icons.home),
                  _icon(Icons.message),
                  _icon(Icons.add),
                  _icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                  _icon(Icons.person_outline),
                ],
              ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
        duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
        curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget _icon(IconData data) {
  return Flexible(child: Icon(data));
}
```

2. Second is use onEnd callback. [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer/AnimatedContainer.html).

[image]

bool isSelected = false;
bool hasFullWidth = true;

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      setState(() {
        isSelected = !isSelected;
        hasFullWidth = false;
      });
    },
    child: Center(
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        padding: isSelected
            ? EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0, horizontal: 12.0)
            : EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0, horizontal: 30.0),
        width: isSelected ? 48 : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.85,
        child: !isSelected && hasFullWidth
            ? Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.home),
                  Icon(Icons.message),
                  Icon(Icons.add),
                  Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                  Icon(Icons.person_outline),
                ],
              )
            : Icon(Icons.favorite),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
        duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
        curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
        onEnd: () {
          if (!isSelected) {
            setState(() {
              hasFullWidth = true;
            });
          }
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```